# Both ArtBox and TrimBox on a page in iText7

Tags: itext7

Its not possible to put a artbox and trimbox on a page with iText7.0.5.0

The source states then only a trimbox or a ArtBox can exist on a page.
This is not true, they can exist both on a page.

Line 615 of PdfPage.java

```
 /**
 * Sets the TrimBox object, that define the intended dimensions of the finished page after trimming.
 *
 * @param rectangle the {@link Rectangle} object to set, expressed in default user space units.
 * @return this {@link PdfPage} instance.
 */
public PdfPage setTrimBox(Rectangle rectangle) {
    if (getPdfObject().getAsRectangle(PdfName.ArtBox) != null) {
        getPdfObject().remove(PdfName.ArtBox);
        Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PdfPage.class);
        logger.warn(LogMessageConstant.ONLY_ONE_OF_ARTBOX_OR_TRIMBOX_CAN_EXIST_IN_THE_PAGE);
    }
    put(PdfName.TrimBox, new PdfArray(rectangle));
    return this;
}

    /**
 * Sets the ArtBox object, that define the extent of the page’s meaningful content
 * (including potential white space) as intended by the page’s creator.
 *
 * @param rectangle the {@link Rectangle} object to set, expressed in default user space units.
 * @return this {@link PdfPage} instance.
 */
public PdfPage setArtBox(Rectangle rectangle) {
    if (getPdfObject().getAsRectangle(PdfName.TrimBox) != null) {
        getPdfObject().remove(PdfName.TrimBox);
        Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PdfPage.class);
        logger.warn(LogMessageConstant.ONLY_ONE_OF_ARTBOX_OR_TRIMBOX_CAN_EXIST_IN_THE_PAGE);
    }
    put(PdfName.ArtBox, new PdfArray(rectangle));
    return this;
}
```

Proposed solutions:

```
  /**
 * Gets the {@link Rectangle} object specified by page's ArtBox, that define the extent of the page’s
 * meaningful content (including potential white space) as intended by the page’s creator.
 *
 * @return the {@link Rectangle} object specified by page's ArtBox, expressed in default user space units.
 *         CropBox by default.
 */
public Rectangle getArtBox() {
    Rectangle artBox = getPdfObject().getAsRectangle(PdfName.ArtBox);
    return artBox == null ? getCropBox() : artBox;
}

/**
 * Sets the TrimBox object, that define the intended dimensions of the finished page after trimming.
 *
 * @param rectangle the {@link Rectangle} object to set, expressed in default user space units.
 * @return this {@link PdfPage} instance.
 */
public PdfPage setTrimBox(Rectangle rectangle) {
    put(PdfName.TrimBox, new PdfArray(rectangle));
    return this;
}
```

Comment: That's strange. It's as if we deliberately wrote code to avoid having an art box and a trim box in the same file. I quickly browsed ISO-32000-2, but I couldn't find any reason why this wouldn't be possible. I'll make an internal ticket for this question, so that further investigation will be done at iText Group.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie I see the changes in these lines were related to PDF/A support, so probably it's all because of PDF/A. But I agree the behavior is probably incorrect and needs to be investigated.

Comment: @Joost Voorhaar The best way to propose changes in code it to use [Pull requests](https://github.com/itext/itext7/pulls)